# Is it advised to index the field if I envision retrieving all records corresponding to positive values in that field?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a table with definition somewhat like the following:

```
create table offset_table (
id serial primary key,
offset numeric NOT NULL,
... other fields...
);
```

The table has about 70 million rows in it.

I envision doing the following query many times

```
select * from offset_table where offset > 0;
```

For speed issues, I am wondering whether it would be advised to create an index like:

```
create index on offset_table(offset);
```

I am trying to avoid creation of unnecessary indices on this table as it is pretty big already.

Comment: So how many rows would be with a positive `offset` column value?

Comment: I would say about 70% have positive `offset`.

Comment: Then it won't be used anyway.

Comment: Can you please explain in an answer? :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in the comments, it would be ~70% of rows that match the `offset > 0` predicate.

In that case the index would not be beneficial, since postgresql (and basically every other DBMS) would prefer a full table scan instead. It happens because it would be faster than jumping between reading the index consequently and the table randomly.

Comment: under what cut off percentage would an index be useful?

Comment: @Alex it's hard to tell the exact number, since the query planner is not as direct, but I'd say that 10-15% would be a good starting point.